# converting a functional component to a class component

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this code which works

```
function Circle(props) {
   var style = {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "1px solid black",
      borderRadius: "100%",
      paddingTop: "98%"
   }
   return (<div style={style}></div>)
}
```

But I want to write it as a class component so I tried

```
class Circle extends React.Component {         
   var style = {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "1px solid black",
      borderRadius: "100%",
      paddingTop: "98%"
   };   
   render() { return(
      <div style={style}></div>
   )}
}
```

The error I get is

```
SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token, expected ( (3:13)
  1 | 
  2 |       class Circle extends React.Component {         
> 3 |          var style = {
```

I googled a fair amount and found articles like these

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00

Based on this I tried various keywords like `static` `cost` and `let` but nothing seems to work.

Coming from java world, why can't I have the style as the property of my class?

don't flame me I just started to learn react and I did google before asking.

https://codepen.io/knows_not_much/pen/mXXEov

Comment: you aren't returning anything from `render`

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: `var` is not valid ins a class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid as per ES6 class spec.

You can initialise your style in the constructor instead:

```
class Circle extends React.Component {       
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.style = {
       backgroundColor: "white",
       border: "1px solid black",
       borderRadius: "100%",
       paddingTop: "98%"
     };
   }     
   render() { return(
      <div style={this.style}></div>
   )}
}
```

or of course just outside the class:

```
const style = {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "1px solid black",
      borderRadius: "100%",
      paddingTop: "98%"
};

class Circle extends React.Component {       
   render() { return(
      <div style={style}></div>
   )}
}
```

or yet another approach, a getter:

```
class Circle extends React.Component {

   get style() {
      return {
          backgroundColor: "white",
          border: "1px solid black",
          borderRadius: "100%",
          paddingTop: "98%"
      };
   }

   render() { return(
      <div style={this.style}></div>
   )}
}
```

Comment: my bad - forgot it was a react component class - updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`var` is not valid in the class definition space. you can simply leave it off:

```js
class Foo {
   style = "bar";
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.style);
```